# Passing dynamic object to an angular module's forRoot()

Tags: angular

I'm using the package `ngx-cookieconsent` which imports the module as:

`const cookieConfig: NgcCookieConsentConfig = {
  "cookie": {
    "domain": "localhost"
  },
  ...
  "theme": "block",
  "content": {
    "policy": "Cookie Policy"
  }
};
...
@NgModule({
 imports: [
    NgcCookieConsentModule.forRoot(cookieConfig)
  ]`

However, the domain property on the config will be set at runtime and so I can't have this defined as a constant. To get round this I have done the following:

Created a `ConfigurationService` that gets the config and stores it:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {

  private configuration: IServerConfiguration;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) { }

  loadConfig() {
    return this.http.get<IServerConfiguration>(this.baseUrl + 'Configuration')
      .pipe(
        tap(config => {
          this.configuration = <IServerConfiguration>(config);
        })
      )
      .toPromise();
  }

  public domain(): string {
    return this.configuration.domain;
  }
}
```

And this is set up as an `APP_INITIALIZER` so that the config is called first:

```
export function loadConfiguration(configService: ConfigurationService) {
  return () => configService.loadConfig();
}

...
 providers: [
    ConfigurationService,   
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: loadConfiguration,
      multi: true,
      deps: [ConfigurationService]
    }],
```

And then have created a class to create my cookieConsentOptions object using the config:

```
@Injectable()
export class CookieConstentService {

  cookieDomain: string;

  constructor(configService: ConfigurationService) {
    this.cookieDomain = configService.domain();
  }

  get cookieConstentOptions(): NgcCookieConsentConfig {
    return {
      "cookie": {
        "domain": this.cookieDomain
      },
      "position": "top-right",      
      "content": {
        "message": "This website uses cookies to ensure you get the best experience on our website."
      }
    };
  }
```

**Issue**

I've got the dependency set up between the configService and the CookieConstentService so that I only create the the cookie options when I have the config values.

However, I am unsure how to pass a dynamic value to the `.forRoot()` of a module. I should be able to do `cookieConsentService.cookieConstentOptions()` to get the object but I'm not sure where to instantiate this to be used in he module import. It takes a dependency so can't just create a new instance myself.

Any ideas how I effectively inject a method into a 3rd party module's `forRoot()`?

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing exaclty the same issue. did you find a solution?

Comment: @wodzu I've posted how I solved this, hopefully it answers it for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posting this question I learnt that the object passed into the `forRoot()` method is essentially a singleton, so if I set any values before it gets initialised then it will use this. The way I implemented this was:

1. Create an instance of the options with the constant/default settings (these won't change between environments):

```
import { NgcCookieConsentConfig } from "ngx-cookieconsent";

export const cookieConsentOptions: NgcCookieConsentConfig  =
{
  "cookie": {
    "domain": "not-set"
  },
  "position": "bottom-right",
  "theme": "block",
  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#df1010",
      "text": "#ffffff",
      "link": "#ffffff"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#ffffff",
      "text": "#000000",
      "border": "transparent"
    }
  },
  "type": "info",
  "content": {
    "message": "This website uses cookies to ensure you get the best experience on our website.",
    "dismiss": "Got it!",
    "deny": "Refuse cookies",
    "link": "Learn more",
    "href": "/cookie-policy",
    "policy": "Cookie Policy",
    "target": "_self"
  } 
};
```

Add an `APP_INITIALIZER` to the appModule which injects the `NgcCookieConsentConfig` object. This will pass in the object created above:

```
...
{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: cookieConfigFactory,
      deps: [HttpClient, NgcCookieConsentConfig, ConfigurationService],
      multi: true
    },
...
```

3. And create the method the used above:

```
export function cookieConfigFactory(http: HttpClient, config: NgcCookieConsentConfig, configService: ConfigurationService) {
  return () => configService.loadConfig().then(x => config.cookie.domain = x.domain)
}
```

I'm getting the value for the cookie domain from a custom config service hence why it's being injected in, yours might be different.

4. Finally in the modules import in appModules, import the CookieConsent module passing in the object created in the first step:

```
NgcCookieConsentModule.forRoot(cookieConsentOptions)
```

Comment: Why the function cookieConfigFactory has an HttpClient parameter that isn't used? Further, I didn't get how setting config.cookie.domain = x.domain changes the corresponding constant cookieConsentOptions attribute. Could you explain better?

Comment: @FernandoCosta the `HttpClient` is probably from when I was copying it from my code and trying to minify it for this answer but missed removing it. It doesn't look like  it's needed as it's not used so can probably remove it. `cookieConsentOptions` is a singleton/constant so only one instance of it. I set the value through the factory as part of the APP_INITIALIZER and then when the app bootstraps the CookieConsentModule uses this instance

Comment: Hi config object created in cookieConfigFactory and passed in forRoot function are totally two different object  right ? as one is created by the angular while injecting and other one is created by you. I want to understand here in factory method you are modifying the object created by angular and how this object is passed to root module ?

Comment: @RahulTokase Nope, they are the same object - it's a singleton so both reference the same instance. First I get a reference to it and set my properties, and then it's injected for  ngx-cookieconsent to use

Comment: Ohk How would Angular know to inject only the object created by you. As this object is not created by Angular DI framework how it would be singleton ? I think yours object will be different than one created by the Angular DI framework when injected.