# I already got environment by useFactory, then how to pass value per environment to AppModule?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have AppModule in angular 11 project.

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot( new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: 'Enter_the_Application_Id_here', 
        authority: 'Enter_the_Cloud_Instance_Id_Here'
        redirectUri: 'Enter_the_Redirect_Uri_Here'
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set to true for Internet Explorer 11
      }
    }), null, null)
  ],
  providers: [MyAppConfig,
  {
      provide: APP_INITITALIZER,
      useFactory: getMyUseFactory,
      deps: [MyAppConfig],
      multi: true
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
export function getMyUseFactory(c: MyAppConfig) {
   return () => c.load();
}
```

The method `load` in `MyAppConfig` can return json value, for example:

```
{
   clientId: '12345',
   env: 'dev'
}
```

or

```
{
   clientId: '67890',
   env: 'qa'
}
```

The environment is set when build the code in pipeline automation CI/CD. Now I want to put the clientId into below instead of hardcode.

```
MsalModule.forRoot( new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: 'Enter_the_Application_Id_here',
```

So my question is that how to apply `useFactory`'s return value to `clientId`?

Comment: You could try the solution in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55120488/passing-dynamic-object-to-an-angular-modules-forroot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a way by myself.

Define a variable then assign it in getMyUseFactory() method.

```
const myId = '';
export function getMyUseFactory(c: MyAppConfig) {
     myId = c.env.Id;
     return () => c.load();
}
```

Then `clientId: myId`